# rank of a matrix series

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $X$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with its rank $rank(X)=a<n$.

How can we show that the rank of the matrix series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X^i \cdot {(X^{T})}^{i}$ is $a$ as well?

Answer (score 1):

Since rank of $X$ is $a$, we have $X = UV^T$, where $U,V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times a}$ and $V^TV, U^TU, V^TU \in \mathbb{R}^{a \times a}$ have full rank $=a$. Hence, $X^k = U(V^TU)^{k-1}V^T$ and $(X^T)^k = V(U^TV)^{k-1}U^T$. This gives us
$$X^k (X^T)^k = U(V^TU)^{k-1}V^TV(U^TV)^{k-1}U^T$$
The key is that the row and column basis of $X^k$ and same as the row and column basis, respectively, of $X$. Hence,
$$\sum_{k=1}^m X^k (X^T)^k = U \left(\sum_{k=1}^m (V^TU)^{k-1}V^TV(U^TV)^{k-1}\right) U^T$$
which is clearly a matrix of rank $a$.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't understand the sentence that the key is that ...

Comment: @YACP Did I ask you to do that?

Comment: @YACP I was coaxed by another user to join back and contribute. And given that this site is just becoming one of those other random forums run by some random IT guys, I have decided to no longer contribute and have requested the stackexchange team to delete my profile over the entire stackexchange network. My previous profile message still holds true: "Useless moderator and thankless users". Now I will have more time for my research instead of helping undeserved, impolite, thankless morons.

Comment: @Shi/Sivaram/Marvis/17762/etc. - one day, your pride will destroy you. You are intelligent, and maybe more than most in these parts, but the cancerous attitude that your embrace can only end in loneliness and misery. Good luck out there.